# Let $f:A \subseteq \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^n$ be a vector-valued-function. If $c \in A$ is a limit point of $A$, show that $f$ is continuous at $c$.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:A \subseteq \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^n$ be a vector-valued-function. If $c \in A$ is a limit point of $A$, show that $f$ is continous at $c$.

**Attempt:**
Since $c$ be a limit point of $A$, then by definition, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $x \in A$ and $x \ne c$ such that $|x-c| < \epsilon$. This is also true for $|x-c |< \frac{\epsilon}{n}$ whenever $n > 0$. To show: $f$ continuous at $c$.
Let $\epsilon > 0$. Pick $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
||f(x)-f(c)||^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^n ||f_i(x) - f_i(c)||^2 \\
&= |f_1(x) - f_1(c)|^2 + \ldots + |f_n(x) - f_n(c)|^2
\end{align*}
I got stucked here. I want to bring the last line to be less than $\epsilon^2 /n$ for each component, but dont know how to approach it. Any ideas?
Also, $f:A \to \Bbb R^n$ usually defined as $f_i(t) = x_i$ for all $t \in A$ and $i=1,2,\ldots, n$.

Comment: This isn't true as written -- it would imply that every function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous (by taking $A=\mathbb{R}$, since then all points are limit points).

Comment: @NickPeterson And then, how to show it ?

Comment: This is completely false, as @NickPeterson explained. Can you post the precise problem from where you receive it?

Comment: the problem was false ?

Comment: but it is a theorem in vector valued function

Comment: Maybe the problem meant that $f$ is continuous on $A$, but this is still false in that case.

Comment: then, should I omitted this theorem ?

Comment: This is false even if $f$ is continuous on $A$. Take $A = (0, 1)$ and $f(x) = 1/x$ on $A$. There is no continuous extension to $0$, which is a limit point of $A$. Where did you find this problem?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop it's from my lecturers note in the class and give it as exercise to proving

Comment: Well as written it is completely false. Are you sure you transcribed it correctly? @NickPeterson and I have both given you reasons for why it is false.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop Yes I did, I'm sure for what I wrote there

Comment: Then your lecturer is incorrect.

Comment: What if the problem changed from continuous to has a derivative at $c$, is it still false ?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop But f is vector valued, why you choose $1/x$ there ?

Comment: I took $n=1$. If you insist on $n>1$, let $f(x) = (1/x, 0)$.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop Ah I see. okay, got it. So, Should I omitted this theorem ?

Comment: I think the conditions required for this to be true are that $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an interval (i.e., connected), $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous on $A$, and $f$ be bounded on $A$.

Comment: I stand corrected. I believe $\sin(1/x)$ on $(0,1)$ is a counter-example. Perhaps $f$ must be uniformly continuous.